# Android WebView ProgressBar setVisibility not working

Tags: android, webview, visibility, android-progressbar

I have added a progress bar on a webview. My problem is when the webview is loading a url and the progress bar shows progress and I hit back button, progress bar still keeps loading till it gets completed and shows up on the back page where it should not.

```
 ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebChromeClient(progressBar));
 private static class CustomWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    private static final int MAX_PROGRESS = 100;
    private final ProgressBar progressBar;

    public CustomWebChromeClient(ProgressBar webProgress) {
        progressBar = webProgress;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView web, int newProgress) {
        boolean stillLoading = isStillLoading(newProgress);
        if (hasWebProgress()) {
            progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            progressBar.setVisibility(stillLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
        super.onProgressChanged(web, newProgress);
    }

    private boolean isStillLoading(int newProgress) {
        return newProgress < MAX_PROGRESS;
    }

    private boolean hasWebProgress() {
        return progressBar != null;
    }
}
```

OnBackPressed, when I try to do

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

this does not work. I can see code hitting this line on a breakpoint. All this is happening in a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

first, there is something wrong in your naming. Inside your WebChromeClient you declare

```
private final ProgressBar ProgressBar;
```

that means your instance has the name of the Class.

second, you should put your ProgressBar outside of the WebView in a Relative or LinearLayout together with the WebView. In the WebViewClient you also have to hide the ProgressBar on finish loading or failed loading.

Comment: name of the variable was a typo here in the code it is private final ProgressBar progressBar. About the other suggestion I do not see any such methods in the class WebChromeClient. I tried a method onUnhandledInputEvent() but that does not catch the back button event.

Comment: WebViewClient, not WebChromeClient!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the webview initiation code into a worker thread like this?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        // webview initiation code

    }
}).start();
```

Here is [how it solved my own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40767263/1827488) & here are [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads).